# Can the same component to be registered as a publisher and subscriber in Google pub-sub

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

Wanted to get some feedback around if the same component/service (currently NodeJS based) which acts as a subscriber, could also act as a publisher in a GCP pub-sub based infrastructure. This is of course in a distributed system meaning the component/service would be deployed to multiple nodes/instances/VM's.

Answer (score 0):

It would be unusual for a single component to act as a publisher and subscriber on the same topic, but having a component that receives messages from a subscription on one topic, does some processing, and then publishes messages to a different topic is very common. This is a way to build asynchronous pipelines with multiple processing steps.